# preg_match string between several special characters on each side

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get rid of all the text contained between MathJax delimiters, for instance `$str1 = blah blah \( 2*(2+2) = 8\) blah blah \[ \int_0^1 f = [F]_0^1 \]`.

As you've probably figured, the delimiters are `\(...\)` and `\[...\]` and the `...` part may contain any of the characters `()[]\`.

Considering only the `\[...\]` case, I've tried this

```
$text = preg_replace("/\\\[.*\\\]/","",$text);
```

but it doesn't match my expressions for some reason, whereas

```
$text = preg_replace("/.\[.*\\\]/","",$text);
```

does match my expressions (but also some unwanted expressions, like `a[...\]`.

So my question is two-fold:

1. What's wrong with `\\\[`?
2. Can I do something better than  the .* in the middle that would say "It's ok to have a `\` or a `]`, but no `\]`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to remove everything that's between `\[ \]` ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV yes, and the `\[\]` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have to use

   `preg_replace("/\\\\\\[.*\\\\\\]/", "", $str1);`

   The pattern parameter to the `preg_replace` function is an ordinary PHP string and therefore `\\` gets replaced by `\` to result in the following regex pattern:

   `/\\\[.*\\\]/`

   The first two backslashes `\\` match a backslash in the subject, the remaining `\[` and `\]` match `[` and `]`, respectively.
2. Yes, you can, using a so-called Negative Lookahead Zero-Width Assertions. Have a look at   http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html for details. In your case, I'd try something like:

   `preg_replace("/\\\\\\[(?:(?!\\\\\\]).)*\\\\\\]/","",$str1);`

   The `?!\\\\\\]` stops a match as soon as `\]` is encountered. The `?:` prevents the outer pair of parentheses from being capturing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regular expression that'll match either of the delimiters:

```
preg_replace('/\\[\[\(].*?\\[\]\)]/', '', $data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it did not work with a bunch of expressions I tried...

Comment: Yep sorry, I was using an online php regex editor...seems to be broken :(